# Prevent Fragment's onCreateView to be always called upon click on Fragment TabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have following code inside my Fragment:

```
    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(activity, getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    tab1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("Tab 1");
        }
    });
    tab2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("Tab 2");
        }
    });
    // ---
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1")
            .setIndicator("Title 1", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_1)), Fragment1.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2")
            .setIndicator("Title 2", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_2)), Fragment2.class, null);
    // ---
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

I observe every time I click my both tab buttons, it will call `onCreateView` my both Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 onCreateView.

Any advise how to prevent it?

Comment: why do you want to prevent it? ViewPagers sometimes load 3 pages with every scroll and there is no problem.

Comment: because there is API call for each of tab and I don't want to burden both server and UX. By the way, previously before I changed into `FragmentTabHost` from `TabHost`, it didn't always call onCreate of each tab's activity.

Comment: no offence but can't you put those API calls some where else? like in call of newInstance that is what I did.!

Comment: I don't want to change current logic behaviour, since I only need to revamp the UI. So I am looking is there any possibility for me to do as what I am asking.